# Equality between Proxy and target object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, proxies

Javascript's new Proxy feature offers some interesting features for debugging. For example you can "defend" an object by putting it behind a Proxy with a `get` handler that throws if you access an undefined property. This helps catch typos and other kinds of mistakes.

This could be used something like this:

```
class Something {
    constructor()
    {
        this.foo = "bar";

        allObjects.push(this);
    }
};

function defend(o)
{
    return new Proxy(o, DebugCheckHandler);
};

let rawSomething = new Something();
let defendedSomething = defend(rawSomething);
```

Code can be diligently written to only deal in terms of `defendedSomething`. However in this example, the `Something` constructor passes `this` somewhere else (to `allObjects`). This ends up having the same effect as using both `rawSomething` and `defendedSomething` across the codebase.

Problems then arise from the fact the proxy reference does not equal its original reference, since `rawSomething !== defendedSomething`. For example, `allObjects.includes(defendedSomething)` will return false if it contains `rawSomething`, because `includes` does a strict `===` check.

Is there a good way to solve this without making too many changes to the code?

Comment: Using globals (or any external variable) inside a constructor is extremely poor engineering, the `allObjects.push(this);` should be outside, e.g. `allObjects.push(rawSomething);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting the `new` operator call [[Construct]], which produces a real instance, you can:

1. Create an object which inherits from the `prototype` of the constructor.
2. Use it as the handler of the proxy.
3. Call the constructor passing the proxy as the `this` value.

```js
function Something() {
  this.foo = "bar";
  allObjects.push(this);
}
function defendIntanceOf(C) {
  var p = new Proxy(Object.create(C.prototype), DebugCheckHandler);
  C.call(p);
  return p;
};
let defendedSomething = defendIntanceOf(Something);
```

Note I used the function syntax instead of the class one in order to be able to use `Function.call` to call [[Call]] with a custom `this` value.

Comment: One problem with this is if `DebugCheckHandler` throws on setting non-existent properties, it will throw as the constructor adds the object properties.

Comment: @AshleysBrain Then make it not throw? Or maybe `var p = new Proxy(new C(), DebugCheckHandler)` if you don't mind pushing an useless object to `allObjects`. Or `var p = new Proxy(Object.assign(Object.create(C.prototype), {foo: void 0}), DebugCheckHandler)` if you now the properties beforehand.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that avoids the debug check handler ever finding false positives in constructors, never pushes a useless object to allObjects, and does not require completely rewriting constructors or otherwise uses a considerably different style.

Comment: @AshleysBrain Are you OK with altering the traps after the object has been constructed? [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/emc6z55t/)

Comment: This does not work for `class`es, which can only be [[construct]]ed but not [[call]]ed. And `Reflect.construct` does take a (subclass) constructor as its third argument, not an instance.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, thanks, it seems I misunderstood `Reflect.construct`; it doesn't help I don't know any working implementation of `Reflect`. And yes, I didn't use the class syntax in order to have [[Call]].

Comment: Oh, I first thought you could work around this by passing something crazy as `newTarget` but I don't think it's possible. Can you have a look at my answer and try to bust it?

Answer (score 0):

Iirc, the only way to influence the `this` value in a constructor - which is what you need here - is through subclassing. I believe (but can't test) that the following should work:

```
function Defended() {
    return new Proxy(this, DebugCheckHandler);
//                   ^^^^ will become the subclass instance
}

class Something extends Defended {
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ these…
    constructor() {
        super();
//      ^^^^^^^ …should be the only changes necessary
//      and `this` is now a Proxy exotic object
        this.foo = "bar";

        allObjects.push(this);
    }
};

let defendedSomething = new Something();
```

Comment: I think the problem is that not all `Something` instances are supposed to be defended, though.

Comment: Hm, in that case you'd need to pass a boolean parameter from the `Something` constructor upwards to `Defended`, and make it like `function Defendable(defend) { if (defend) return new Proxy …; }`

Comment: No, the real problem is if the DebugCheckHandler throws on adding non-existent properties (which I want it to), then the Something class constructor will throw when adding the "foo" property.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like you really need to adapt the constructor code then and decide explicitly where you want to use the proxy (for passing around) and where the target (for initialisation). Of course you could also wrap the constructor to create a (temporal) zone during which adding properties is allowed, but that can backfire just as well.